# Create an icon/Shortcut in main menu

Tags: 20.04, gnome-dash

I create the following SweetHome3D.desktop file and put in `./local/share/applications` (Ubuntu 20.04)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sweet Home 3D
Exec=/home/pedro/Programas Baixados/SweetHome3D-6.5.2/SweetHome3D
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/pedro/Programas Baixados/SweetHome3D-6.5.2
Icon=/home/pedro/Programas Baixados/SweetHome3D-6.5.2/SweetHome3DIcon.png
```

I execute `r` command in ALT + F2, but still not showing

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces are not recognized in Ubuntu file paths.

You should either rename the directory so there is not a space, or you can use `\`  to denote the space in the file path.  It should also work to use quotations.

Examples

```
Exec=/home/pedro/Programas\ Baixados/SweetHome3D-6.5.2/SweetHome3D
```

Or

```
Exec="/home/pedro/Programas Baixados/SweetHome3D-6.5.2/SweetHome3D"
```

Comment: Just renamed to "Programas_Baixados" and still don't appear in main menu...

Comment: Oh, one line still with space. Just fixed and now the icon appear. Thanks :)